# How to have a swipe gesture back animation

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I have a swipe gesture which set to "right" (swipe left to right) and the segue go back to the previous view controller.

If I run the app, the gesture works (go back) but the animation appears from right to left (like I'm going to the next page instead of the previous one)

How can I change the animation to go from Left to Right? Can it be done via storyboard?

Thank you

Comment: Can you show your code? I think you are push a viewcontrolelr which make animation right to left...?

Comment: I just used storyboard. I dont have any code. Drag and Drop the gestore recognizer and then CTRL and drag to the new ViewController.